# Word for a source of mental-strength

Tags: single-word-requests

What would be a term for  something/somebody that gives a person confidence, motivation, strength or hope in times of trouble? The scenario I have in mind is of a person facing a real life-death situation, they're absolutely overcome by the atmosphere at that moment, to act at such a time seems almost impossible/worthless to them. Then suddenly they get a glimpse of the most important person/thing that matters to them. This inspires them to act and fight in that situation. How would we describe this person or thing? A motivator seems a rather uninteresting or dull term to me. Following two scenarios might further help understand the nature of the person/thing in question.

1) Jenna is a middle-aged woman, fighting cancer, her situation is really hopeless, she doesn't think living is worthwhile, but then she thinks about her baby, who's still very young and needs his mother to help him find his feet in the world. This gives Jenna a reason to persist in her cause to fight cancer for a little longer. The boy gives her a hope, reason, strength and motivation to live.

2) Arthur, plays as a striker for a football club. His team are mid-way through their match with their local-rivals, and haven't scored a goal yet, they know if they don't win the game, their cup-run would be over, Arthur sees the look on his team-mates and the coach, they're all looking very glum. This invigorates Arthur, albeit paradoxically, to give in his best. He scores a goal and his team win the match. The look on the team-mates gave Arthur something to fight for.

Comment: I think *my light in the darkness* is very apt here. It seems to suit the first example well.

Comment: It is, but I'm looking for a single-term, not a phrase...

Answer (score 5):

I like the word "Inspiration" for that.

Edited to include the word "epiphany" at the request of the original poaster.

Comment: Yes inspiration would work, but I was thinking what if someone is in a life-death situation and they're completely taken over by the atmosphere of that moment, and then suddenly something happens, like they see someone, maybe their mentor, friend either in their mind's eye or in real and their confidence, hope or strength is restored to fight in that situation. I think inspiration is a relative term, but I'm thinking something specific relating to the context I've just given. I must consider revising the question now.

Comment: In that case, a stronger word is epiphany.

Comment: Wow that's a very nice word. You could change your answer with it, I'll upvote you. :)

Comment: Done. Just for you ...

: )

Comment: I don't think that is what epiphany means.

Comment: I didn't say it's the exact term I was looking for, but it's relative to the context so I can't disregard it completely.

Comment: Transformation, and 'transformative', may have some weight here.

Comment: @FatherLuke You're losing the gist of the post now. :)

Comment: Well, based on your edit, the change which comes about indicates to me transformative behavior. A transformation is, loosely, defined: '  a complete or major change in someone's or something's appearance, form, etc.

But, yeah..

Comment: You could go so far as to use **transfiguration**, but that's generally reserved for extreme cases: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transfiguration

Comment: But @FatherLuke, 'the transformed character'' of the person isn't the question, it's what(person/thing) leads to that transformation we're looking to describe...

Comment: Ah. Goddit @Andy Semyonov.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit esoteric, but one possibility is **tonic**. Its concrete connotation is medicinal, similar to *elixir*, but dictionary.com also defines it as "anything invigorating physically, mentally, or morally".

> 1) Jenna is a middle-aged woman, fighting cancer, her situation is really hopeless, she doesn't think living is worthwhile, but then she thinks about her baby, who's still very young and needs his mother to help him find his feet in the world. This gives Jenna a reason to persist in her cause to fight cancer for a little longer. **The boy becomes her tonic.**
>
> 2) Arthur, plays as a striker for a football club. His team are mid-way through their match with their local-rivals, and haven't scored a goal yet, they know if they don't win the game, their cup-run would be over, Arthur sees the look on his team-mates and the coach, they're all looking very glum. This invigorates Arthur, albeit paradoxically, to give in his best. He scores a goal and his team win the match. **The look on his team-mates' faces was Arthur's tonic.**

Another possibility is **stimulant**. Relative to *tonic*, it is more superficial and immediate, and does not imply the existence of a problem.

Another possibility is **buoy**. This one does not actively inspire you to act, merely keeps you from drowning in despair.

Comment: Very well @vladkornea, I'm happy with these terms, they all seem relative to the context given in my OP, but I'd admit I'm not fully satisfied yet, I think there's still a better word we're all failing to think of that would more felicitous to both egs.

Answer (score 0):

"Epiphany" does not imply a causative reaction - which your question clearly implies.

The expression, ***"A shot in the arm"***, is often used to describe the thing which inspires:

"Memories of my time in a wheelchair gave me **a shot in the arm** to finish the marathon."

("A shot" refers to 'an injection', like a doctor would give you - not a punch, or a bullet.) (US)

Comment: Thanks, I like that phrase, but still I'm looking for a single term, however annoying it may sound. :)